# Python: Replace elements of one list with those of another if condition is met

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have two lists one called src with each element in this format:

```
['SOURCE:  filename.dc : 1 : a/path/: description','...]
```

And one called base with each element in this format:

```
['BASE: 1: another/path','...]
```

I am trying to compare the base element's number (in this case it's 4) with the source element's number (in this case it's 1).

If they match then i want to replace the source element's number with the base element's path.

Right now i can split the source element's number with a for loop like this:

```
    for w in source_list:
      src_no=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), w.split(':'))[2])
```

And i can split the base element's path and number with a for loop like this:

```
        for r in basepaths:
          base_no=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), r.split(':'))[1])
          base_path=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), r.split(':'))[2])
```

I expect the new list to look like ( base on the example of the two elements above):

```
['SOURCE:  filename.dc : another/path : a/path/: description','...]
```

the src list is a large list with many elements, the base list is usually three or four elements long and is only used to translate into the new list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have time to answer this, but if you want any decent answer, you need to answer this question: Are both lists of equal length? Which items do you want to compare? Only, say Base at position 0 with Source at position 0, or Base at position 0 with all sources? If possible, please expand a bit on the list examples, and provide the expected output those lists would produce.

Comment: Do you want to compare the elements in same index? And is the length of both lists equal?

Comment: And please add the information requested to the question as an edit if possible, not in the comments! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked something together for you, which I think should do what you want:

```
base_list = ['BASE: 1: another/path']
base_dict = dict()

# First map the base numbers to the paths
for entry in base_list:
    n, p = map(lambda s: s.strip(), entry.split(':')[1:])
    base_dict[n] = p

source_list = ['SOURCE:  filename.dc : 1 : a/path/: description']

# Loop over all source entries and replace the number with the base path of the numbers match   
for i, entry in enumerate(source_list):
    n = entry.split(':')[2].strip()
    if n in base_dict:
        new_entry = entry.split(':')
        new_entry[2] = base_dict[n]
        source_list[i] = ':'.join(new_entry)
```

Be aware that this is a hacky solution, I think you should use regexp (look into the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module) to extract number and paths and when replacing the number.

This code also alters a list while iterating over it, which may not be the most pythonic thing to do.

Comment: sorry i've found a problem with the code, you seem to have lost the colons in the list. i need these in there otherise my script doesnt work.

Comment: Yea, it seems like I forgot it, @RitchieRamnial. It  should work now though.

Answer (score 0):

So there is one large list that will be sequentially browsed and a shorter one. I would turn the short one into a mapping to find immediately for each item of the first list whether there is a match:

```
base = {}
for r in basepaths:
    base_no=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), r.split(':'))[1])
    base_path=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), r.split(':'))[2])
    base[base_no] = base_path
for w in enumerate source_list:
    src_no=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), w.split(':'))[2])
    if src_no in base:
        path = base[src_no]
        # stuff...
```

Comment: they are both lists of differing sizes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(source_list)):
    for b in basepaths:
        if source_list[i].split(":")[2].strip() == b.split(":")[1].strip():
            source_list[i] = ":".join(source_list[i].split(":")[:3] + [b.split(":")[2]] + source_list[i].split(":")[4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

just get rid of the [] part of the splits:

```
src=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), w.split(':')))
base=(map(lambda s: s.strip(), r.split(':')))

>> src
>> ['SOURCE', 'filename.dc', '1', 'a/path/', 'description']
```

the base will similarly be a simple list
now just replace the proper element:

```
src[2] = base[2]
```

then put the elements back together if necessary:

```
src = ' : '.join(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def separate(x, separator = ':'):
    return tuple(x.split(separator))

sourceList = map(separate, source)

baseDict = {}
for b in map(separate, base):
    baseDict[int(b[1])] = b[2]


def tryFind(number):
    try:
        return baseDict[number]
    except:
        return number


result = [(s[0], s[1], tryFind(int(s[2])), s[3]) for s in sourceList]
```

This worked for me, it's not the best, but a start